# Lie Symmetry method for solving perfect fluid SEM Tensor Einstein Equations

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, computational-physics, software

Suppose that we have the field equations $$G_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu},$$ with $\kappa=\frac{8 \pi G}{c^4}$ and $G_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu}-\frac12Rg_{\mu\nu}$. We assume that our matter distribution takes the form of  a perfect fluid in the rest-frame, that is $T_{\mu\nu}=diag(\rho,p,p,p)$. With a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ having components $g_{\mu\nu}=diag(-e^{2\phi(r)},\left(1-\frac{b(r)}{r}\right)^{-1},r^2,r^2 \sin^2\theta)$. Upon solving for our Einstein tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$we obtain the equations for our unknown metric functions $\phi(r)$ and $b(r)$. We now have that $$G_{00}=\kappa\rho$$ and $$G_{11}=\kappa p.$$ Upon plugging the equations into Mathematica, we find that it cant me solved in this form, but can be solved if we have $$G_{00}=0$$ and  $$G_{11}=0.$$ Whilst trying to find a solution to this issue we encounter the fact that perfect fluid EFEs can often be solved via applying Lie Symmetries. How do we find these Lie Symmetries of a given system of highly coupled non-linear hyperbolic-elliptic second order partial differential equations? Furthermore, after identifying the symmetries of the PDEs how can we apply the symmetries to the PDEs such that we can reduce them to something that Mathematica can solve?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? It is very unclear to me. You are saying that the given metric does not admit perfect fluid as matter field, right?

Comment: @Immanuel im saying that mathematica cannot solve the given equations when presented. Thus, I am looking for a method to indentify lie symmetries of the 2 PDEs so I can reduce them.

Comment: Still unclear. If you are sayin that the metric does not admit perfect fluid, then what's the point of this? Although I don't think that the metric does not admit this matter.

Comment: It does admit it.  The problem is that I am not aware on how to solve them, hence I am trying to figure out how to identify and understand lie symmetries.